# creating fatjar from obsufucated jar and library jar depedencies?

Tags: java, gradle, proguard, fatjar

I have a a fatjar, which is a deployable jar with main method defined, and which depedencies are copied via gradle.

This works fine.

I want to obsufucate/encrypt my jar.

Using proguard I can obsufucate myJar, and specify libraryjars.  How do I get a farJar created from the obsufucated jar and its dependencies ?

So far I can only obsufucate the original jar, not obsufucate and bundle as fat jar.

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Metriculous',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'au.com.metriculous.MetriculousServer'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

my proguard task looks pretty much the same as the samples, the library jars don't get added to jar as fatJar. And I don't want to define lots of rules for not obsufucating injars, which I could do if I simply obsufucate the whole fatjar ?